# How to configure `TracingConfig` on cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to enable `x-ray` for my lambda function and below is the template file:

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
```

I got below error when I deploy via `sam deploy` command:

```
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [HelloWorldFunction] is invalid. property TracingConfig not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function
```

It shows the `TracingConfig` is not defined. What is the correct way to configure that for my lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this [docs](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction), it should be `Tracing` only. So the correct one should be as below

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Tracing: Active
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
```